(Anti) Commutation relation of derivative of the fermionic operator
While deriving Semiconductor Bloch equation, I stumbled upon a commutation relation that I have never seen before. It looks like,
$$[\alpha_k^{\dagger}\alpha_k, \alpha_{k'}^{\dagger}(\nabla_{k'}\alpha_{k'})]$$
where $\alpha_k$ is the fermionic annihilation operator i.e. it follows $\{\alpha_k, \alpha_{k'}^{\dagger}\} = \delta_{k,k'}$. I took the derivative term from Equation 2 of this reference [1]. If you look at the 2nd term of equation 2, it correspondes to intra current of electron/hole within a band. From their solution in equation 5, I guess that the answer to this relation should be,
$$= \nabla_k(\alpha_k^{\dagger}\alpha_k)$$
I was able to do a couple of steps,
$$= [\alpha_k^{\dagger}\alpha_k, \alpha_{k'}^{\dagger}](\nabla_{k'}\alpha_{k'})+\alpha_{k'}^{\dagger}[\alpha_k^{\dagger}\alpha_k, (\nabla_{k'}\alpha_{k'})]$$
$$ = \delta_{k,k'}\alpha_{k'}^{\dagger}(\nabla_{k'}\alpha_{k'})+\alpha_{k'}^{\dagger}[\alpha_k^{\dagger}\alpha_k, (\nabla_{k'}\alpha_{k'})]$$
However, I don't know how to proceed for the second term. If anyone can help even with some useful suggestion that would be great.


Please give a reference. 2. Do you know what should come out? 3. How is $\nabla_k \alpha_k$ defined?


@TobiasFünke I have cited the paper where I took the term, I am following their steps only. I am not sure how the derivative of $\alpha_k$ is defined, it is not defined in the reference also.

The gradient is a linear process and the commutator is distributive. Therefore, you should be able to pull the gradient to the outside and evaluate the commutator first. Then you'll end up with the gradient of a Dirac delta.

@flippiefanus But there will be terms like $\nabla_{k'}(\alpha_k^{\dagger}\alpha_k)$, right?

No, I don't see how such terms would come about.
